# WebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer configureClientInboundChannel doenst register interceptor

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, websocket

I'm struggling to override WebSocketSecurity by introducing my own *AuthorizationChannelInterceptor*. I'm not abdle to do so, my requests end up being rejected by default interceptor. **Spring boot 3.0.6**

##### The default AuthorizationChannelInterceptor:

```
public final class AuthorizationChannelInterceptor implements ChannelInterceptor {
    private Supplier<Authentication> authentication = this.getAuthentication(SecurityContextHolder.getContextHolderStrategy());
    private final Log logger = LogFactory.getLog(this.getClass());
    private final AuthorizationManager<Message<?>> preSendAuthorizationManager;
    private AuthorizationEventPublisher eventPublisher = new NoopAuthorizationEventPublisher();

    public AuthorizationChannelInterceptor(AuthorizationManager<Message<?>> preSendAuthorizationManager) {
        Assert.notNull(preSendAuthorizationManager, "preSendAuthorizationManager cannot be null");
        this.preSendAuthorizationManager = preSendAuthorizationManager;
    }

    public Message<?> preSend(Message<?> message, MessageChannel channel) {
        this.logger.debug(LogMessage.of(() -> {
            return "Authorizing message send";
        }));
        AuthorizationDecision decision = this.preSendAuthorizationManager.check(this.authentication, message);
        this.eventPublisher.publishAuthorizationEvent(this.authentication, message, decision);
        if (decision != null && decision.isGranted()) {
            this.logger.debug(LogMessage.of(() -> {
                return "Authorized message send";
            }));
            return message;
        } else {
            this.logger.debug(LogMessage.of(() -> {
                return "Failed to authorize message with authorization manager " + this.preSendAuthorizationManager + " and decision " + decision;
            }));
            throw new AccessDeniedException("Access Denied");
        }
    }

...
}
```

Resulting in exception

```
Caused by: org.springframework.security.access.AccessDeniedException: Access Denied
    at org.springframework.security.messaging.access.intercept.AuthorizationChannelInterceptor.preSend(AuthorizationChannelInterceptor.java:74) ~[spring-security-messaging-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.messaging.support.AbstractMessageChannel$ChannelInterceptorChain.applyPreSend(AbstractMessageChannel.java:181) ~[spring-messaging-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8]
    at org.springframework.messaging.support.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:135) ~[spring-messaging-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8]
    ... 42 common frames omitted
```

taking place inside `AuthorizationChannelInterceptor.preSend`.

To be even more specific, it rejects my request basing on this:

```
    private boolean isGranted(Authentication authentication) {
        return authentication != null && authentication.isAuthenticated() && this.isAuthorized(authentication);
    }
```

Where authentication is always anonymous

***Can you please advise how to override this? What am I doing wrong here?***

### Below is my basic WebScoketConfig

```
package com.example.websocketchat.socket;

import com.example.websocketchat.stomp_principal.CustomHandshakeHandler;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.messaging.simp.config.ChannelRegistration;
import org.springframework.messaging.simp.config.MessageBrokerRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.socket.config.annotation.EnableWebSocketMessageBroker;
import org.springframework.web.socket.config.annotation.StompEndpointRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.socket.config.annotation.WebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker
public class WebSocketConfig implements WebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void configureClientInboundChannel(ChannelRegistration registration) {
        registration.interceptors(new AuthChannelInterceptor());
    }

    @Override
    public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry config) {
        config.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/websocket");
        config.enableSimpleBroker("/global", "/user");
        config.setUserDestinationPrefix("/user");
    }

    @Override
    public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry registry) {
        registry
                .addEndpoint("/websocket")
                .setAllowedOrigins("http://localhost:5173")
                .setHandshakeHandler(new CustomHandshakeHandler())
                .withSockJS();
    }
}
```

---

### My custom Interceptor, for now just to print things and see if working

```
package com.example.websocketchat.socket;

import org.springframework.messaging.Message;
import org.springframework.messaging.MessageChannel;
import org.springframework.messaging.simp.stomp.StompHeaderAccessor;
import org.springframework.messaging.support.ChannelInterceptor;
import org.springframework.messaging.support.MessageHeaderAccessor;

public class AuthChannelInterceptor implements ChannelInterceptor {


  @Override
  public Message<?> preSend(Message<?> message, MessageChannel channel) {
    System.out.println("Message auth interceptor");
    StompHeaderAccessor accessor = MessageHeaderAccessor.getAccessor(message, StompHeaderAccessor.class);
    assert accessor != null;
    String authorization = accessor.getFirstNativeHeader("Authorization");
    System.out.println(authorization);

    return message;
  }
}
```

---

### As well as SecurityConfig

```
package com.example.websocketchat.security;

import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.servlet.PathRequest;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationProvider;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.web.SecurityFilterChain;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter;
import org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CookieCsrfTokenRepository;

import static org.springframework.security.config.http.SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@AllArgsConstructor
public class SecurityConfig {

    private final JwtAuthenticationFilter jwtAuthenticationFilter;
    private final AuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider;

    @Bean
    SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.csrf().csrfTokenRepository(CookieCsrfTokenRepository.withHttpOnlyFalse());
        http.csrf().ignoringRequestMatchers("/auth/**");
        http.csrf().ignoringRequestMatchers("/chat/**");
        http.csrf().ignoringRequestMatchers("/global");
        http.csrf().ignoringRequestMatchers("/global/**");
        http.csrf().ignoringRequestMatchers("/user/**");

        http.headers().frameOptions().sameOrigin();
        http.sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(STATELESS);
        http.authorizeHttpRequests((authorize) -> authorize
                .requestMatchers(PathRequest.toH2Console()).permitAll()
        );
        http.authorizeHttpRequests().requestMatchers("/auth/**").permitAll();
        http.authorizeHttpRequests().requestMatchers("/admin-panel/**").hasAuthority("ADMIN");
        http.authorizeHttpRequests().requestMatchers("/csrf-token").hasAuthority("USER");
        http.authorizeHttpRequests().requestMatchers("/websocket/**").permitAll();
        http.authorizeHttpRequests().requestMatchers("/chat/**").permitAll();
        http.authorizeHttpRequests().anyRequest().denyAll();

        http.authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider);
        http.addFilterBefore(jwtAuthenticationFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
        return http.build();
    }
}
```

---

### POM.XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.6</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>websocket-chat</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>websocket-chat</name>
    <description>websocket-chat</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-websocket</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-messaging</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
            <artifactId>jjwt-api</artifactId>
            <version>0.11.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
            <artifactId>jjwt-impl</artifactId>
            <version>0.11.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
            <artifactId>jjwt-jackson</artifactId>
            <version>0.11.5</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```